# Mouse Event Handling To Create new Populated JFrames

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I am seeing some behavior I really do not understand. In the first bit of code, when run() is called, the JFrames pop up, and the JPanels populate. In the second bit of code, the JFrames pop up but the JFrames do not populate and the windows seem irresponsive.

```
final Class g = TowerView.class
final ArrayList<Class> s = (ArrayList<Class>) sorters.clone();
final Quantifiable [] d = InventoryItem.getRandomArray(SIZE); 
run (s, g, d);
```

This does NOT work:

```
final Class g = TowerView.class
final ArrayList<Class> s = (ArrayList<Class>) sorters.clone();
final Quantifiable [] d = InventoryItem.getRandomArray(SIZE); 
runButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        run(s, g, d);  
    }
});
```

Comment: I JUST figured out how to do it... I was always looking for something that says "Accept"

Comment: I agree that threading may be an issue here, but it's hard to guess where the code bogs down without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the operation inside event listener i.e, run(s,g,d) command in another thread.

Excerpt from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html

> The most important rule to keep in mind about event listeners is that
>   they should execute very quickly. Because all drawing and
>   event-listening methods are executed in the same thread, a slow
>   event-listener method can make the program seem unresponsive and slow
>   to repaint itself. If you need to perform some lengthy operation as
>   the result of an event, do it by starting up another thread (or
>   somehow sending a request to another thread) to perform the operation.
>   For help on using threads, see Concurrency in Swing.

Comment: +1, Also see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and a Swing related solution.